# Navigating from one component to another within a view

Tags: lightning-aura-components, navigatetocomponent

I revisited my existing components to correct navigation by using lightning:navigation approach

My scenario : I have a component that I have embedded inside an account page view. The component has buttons that is used to navigate to other components via force:navigatetocomponent

Now that this attribute is deprecated how do I navigate inside the same view between components?  If I use the pagerefernece object it redirectes me to a complete new url. How do I preserve the url and the view of the standard record I am on and still navigate to the component 2 using the pagereference method

My design is more like screen flow that navigates to different screens based on user input that needs to be embedded as it's own view inside account oppty and contact object as a custom component

Comment: Have you explored simply creating/destroying components dynamically?

Comment: @sebastian nope. I relied on the navigate approach all along. I wanted to hear from the bigger community if this is a use case that can still be done via nav API. If not then that's the next approach to look into.